# Cgroups /sys/fs/cgroup is empty on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cgroups

I am new to `cgroup`. I want to use `cgroup` to bind `Qemu` to some CPUs. I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.3 with my own compiled kernel `3.11.0+`.
Below is some output of my commands.

```
root@xiao-laptop:~/tamlok# service cgconfig start
start: Job failed to start
root@xiao-laptop:~/tamlok# ls /sys/fs/cgroup/
root@xiao-laptop:~/tamlok# cat /proc/mounts | grep cgroup
root@xiao-laptop:~/tamlok# lssubsys --al
cpuset
cpu
cpuacct
devices
freezer
blkio
perf_event
```

`/sys/fs/cgroup/` being empty really confused me. I don't know what should I do next to achieve my target. It seems that the `cgroup` is not mounted? So what's wrong with this? If you need any info about my platform to solve it, please let me know.

Actually I didn't know the whole process to config and use the `cgroup`. Or you could help me out with this step by step. I am afraid that lacking some necessary configuration before resulted in this problem.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I read the kernel documentation about `cgroups` and `cpusets`, and there is a detail description about how to create and use `cgroups` step by step.
The problem here was that I didn't mount the `cgroups`. The solution is given below.

```
mount -t tmpfs cgroup_root /sys/fs/cgroup
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
mount -t cgroup cpuset -o cpuset /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/
```

Then we can see a cpuset directory and there are files inside to modify the properties of the cpuset.
Thanks very much! Hope this will help someone!

Comment: Note for future readers: if you're using a distribution with systemd, you don't need to manually mount cgroups as systemd will do it.  But not for cpusets; see my question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466166/135943